# Sampling given joint probability density

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

When I have single random variable given by its probability density function $f_X$ I can compute the quantile function $Q_X$ (inverse CDF) and sample like $Q_X(U)$ where $U$ is uniform from $[0, 1]$ (by [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)).

If I have joint density function $f_{X, Y}$ I could compute marginal density of $X$, sample $X$ like before, compute conditional density of $Y$ given $X = x$ and again sample $Y$.

But the above seems like conditioning on an event with probability zero and there is the [Borel-Kolmogorov paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox) (nice talk: [Snow Xueyin Zhang - "The Borel-Kolmogorov Paradox as a Paradox for Physical Chance"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3_juDqR5Ks)).

1. Under what assumptions am I allowed to sample using marginal distribution? Are there any considerations when sampling using a computer?
2. What is the meaning of conditional probability density function $f_{X \mid Y}$? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution) states that it need not to be invariant under coordinate transformations. Is it really conditioned on an event with probability zero?

Comment: I do not see the Borel-Kolmogorov paradox applying here, if you can find the inverse of the marginal CDF and the inverse of the conditional CDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see the Borel-Kolmogorov paradox applying here, if you can find the inverse of the marginal CDF and the inverse of the conditional CDF.

Let's take an [example where we know the Borel-Kolmogorov paradox occurs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277388/pdf-of-sum-of-exponentials-conditioned-on-equality)

- We sample for $Y$ and $Z$ where the joint density is $f_{Y,Z}(y,z) = \dfrac{ye^{-y}}{(z+1)^2}\mathbf{1}_{\{y\geq 0, z \geq 0\}}$. We have $f_{Z}(z) = \dfrac{1}{(z+1)^2}\mathbf{1}_{\{z \geq 0\}}$ and $f_{Y \mid Z}(y \mid z) = ye^{-y}\mathbf{1}_{\{y\geq 0\}}$ - there is a slight issue with using the inverse CDF of a gamma distribution, but computers can solve that.  We are interested in $X_1 =\frac{YZ}{Z+1}$ and $X_2 =\frac{Y}{Z+1}$
- We sample for $U$ and $V$ where the joint density is $f_{U,V}(u,v) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-u}\mathbf{1}_{\{u\geq |v|\}}$ . We have  $f_{V}(v) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|v|}$ and $f_{U \mid V}(u \mid v) = e^{|v|-u}\mathbf{1}_{\{u\geq |v|\}}$. We are interested in $X_3 =\frac12(U+V)$ and $X_4 =\frac12(U-V)$

It turns out that following your algorithm  $(X_1,X_2)$ and $(X_3,X_4)$ have the same joint distributions involving exponential distributions with rate $1$

The Borel-Kolmogorov paradox is that $f_{X_1 \mid Z=1}(x) = 4x \exp(-2x)$, a gamma distribution, while $f_{X_3 \mid V=0}(x) = 2\exp(-2x)$, an exponential distribution with half the mean of the gamma distribution,  so not the same even though $Z=1 \iff X_1=X_2$ and $V=0 \iff X_3=X_4$, but this does not affect your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that @Henry is right. The sampling should work and one could argue that in each rectangle $[a, b] \times [c, d]$ it gives the right probability $\Pr[X \in [a, b], Y \in [c, d]]$ using Fubini's theorem.

However it holds up to measure zero (which is often the case in probability and should not be surprizing as integrals "do not see measure zero sets"):

Let
$$f_{X, Y}(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
  1 & y = 1/2, x \in [2, 3] \\
  1 & y \in [0, 1/2) \cup (1/2, 1], x \in [0, 1] \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

If sampling $Y$ first and getting $Y = 1/2$ (with probability zero) then we sample $X \in [2, 3]$.

If we first sample $X$ then $X \in [0, 1]$ and $Y \in [0, 1]$ and it could happen that $Y = 1/2$ (with probability zero again).