# Intuition behind conditioning to events with probability zero

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

What's the intuition behind why the conditional expectation w.r.t. a $\sigma$-algebra allows us to condition to events with zero probability?

For example, let’s say we have two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. We define the conditional probability density function of $Y$ given $X=x_0$, as $$f_{Y|X}(y,x_0)=\frac{f_{XY}(x_0,y)}{f_X(x_0)}.$$

Even though in this definition $f_X$ has to be strictly greater than $0$, we are still conditioning to an event with probability zero $\mathbb{P}(X=x_0)=0$, as $X$ is a continuous r.v.

I understand that the concept of conditional expectation of a random variable (and conditional probability of an event) to a $\sigma$-algebra was introduced in order to deal with conditioning to events with probability zero, but I haven’t quite grasped the intuition behind this.

Comment: It can lead to the [Borel–Kolmogorov paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox).  See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277388/pdf-of-sum-of-exponentials-conditioned-on-equality

Comment: So you have to define your conditional probability as a limit: for example in your case, you might use the limit of the distribution of $Y$ conditioned on $x_0 -\epsilon_1 < X < x_0 +\epsilon_2$ as $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \to 0^+$.  That means you are conditioning on events of positive probability which is safe and, providing that there is a single limiting distribution, then you might be happy with that result.

Comment: @Henry I understand what you said, but I still don’t get the link between that and the conditioning to a $\sigma$-algebra. I mean, why this type of conditional expectation and conditional probability allows to deal with probability zero events?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that without further information, you cannot safely condition on events of probability zero.  As an example where you might have more information, perhaps $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal N(X, \tau^2)$ so given $X=x_0$ you might have the conditional distribution $Y \sim \mathcal N(x_0, \tau^2)$. But more generally you should look at the conditional distribution on an event of probability zero as the limit (if it exists) of conditional distributions on events of positive probability

Comment: Basically the point of the Borel-Kolmogorov paradox is that we do not really condition on events of probability zero, we take a limit of events of small probability which converge setwise to the desired event. In the most general situation, the result of the final conditioning has a "signature" of how the limit was taken.

Comment: Thank you. But why do we specifically need conditioning to $\sigma$-algebra in order to use this limit construction? In _A. Klenke (2020), Probability Theory (3rd ed.), p. 195_ the author refers to $E[X|\mathcal{F}]$ in relation to conditioning to probability 0 events, and an example similar to the one @Henry made.

Comment: $E[X \mid \mathcal{F}]$ achieves this construction by itself without having to do it by hand.

Answer (score -1):

The fact that $\mathbb{P}(X=x_0)=0$ (because $X$ is continuous r.v.) doesn't affect to the conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(Y\in\mathbf{B}|X=x_0)$ where $\mathbf{B}$ is some subset of the outcome space of $Y$ (i.e. the set contains all possible values of $Y$). Here's some image to aid your intuition:

[image: conditional probability]

To see why, denote by $\mathbf{A}$ the range of $Y$, then the probability of $Y$ in the region $\mathbf{B}$ given $X=x_0$ is:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Y\in\mathbf{B}|X=x_0)&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\mathbb{P}(Y\in\mathbf{B}|x_0\le X\le x_0+\epsilon)\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y\in\mathbf{B}, x_0\le X\le x_0+\epsilon)}{\mathbb{P}(x_0\le X\le x_0+\epsilon)}\hspace{1.5em}\text{Bayes' theorem}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\int_{\mathbf{B}}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\epsilon}f_{XY}(x, y)\ dxdy}{\mathbb{P}(Y\in\mathbf{A}, x_0\le X\le x_0+\epsilon)}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\int_{\mathbf{B}}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\epsilon}f_{XY}(x, y)\ dxdy}{\int_{\mathbf{A}}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\epsilon}f_{XY}(x, y)\ dxdy}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\int_{\mathbf{B}}f_{XY}(x_0, y)\epsilon\ dy}{\int_{\mathbf{A}}f_{XY}(x_0, y)\epsilon\ dy}\\
&=\frac{\int_{\mathbf{B}}f_{XY}(x_0, y)\ dy}{\int_{\mathbf{A}}f_{XY}(x_0, y)\ dy}.\\
\end{align}
$$

The right-hand side of the last equality doesn't contain the infinitesimal value $\epsilon$ anymore and thus $\mathbb{P}(X=x_0)=0$ doesn't affect its value.

Taking derivative of both sides, we'll get the formula as you mentioned in the question (note that $\mathbf{B}$ doesn't appear in this formula since all the terms are probability (density) functions):

$$
f_{Y|X}(y,x_0)=\frac{f_{XY}(x_0,y)}{f_X(x_0)}.
$$