Conditional probability on a zero measure set
I have a particular application of algorithm in head and is trying to justify its use theoretically.
Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a state space, say Euclidean. There exists a partition of this space, $\{\mathcal{X}_i\}_{i\in I}$, $I$ is potentially also uncountable. However, each $\mathcal{X}_i$ might also be uncountable, but with lebesgue measure zero (such as lines in a two dimensional space).
Say there's a transition $K$, such that it transforms a point $x\in \mathcal{X}_i$ to another point in $\mathcal{X}_i$, in a uniformly random way.
Now the question is, how to define this $K(x,A)$ properly for any measurable set $A$? This is easy if $\mathcal{X}_i$ all has measure greater than zero as i can then define it to be
$$K(x,A)=\frac{\mu(A\cap \mathcal{X}_i)}{\mu(\mathcal{X}_i)}, x\in\mathcal{X}_i,$$ where $\mu$ is the lebesgue measure. However, this is not viable when $\mu(\mathcal{X}_i)=0$. I know one way to do so is taking the limit of the condition, but not sure thats applicable here.
$\mathcal{X}_i$ being uncountable might also be an issue as it's uniform over the set. but i guess i can restrict the space to be bounded if have to.
Thank you in advance!

$\mu(\mathcal{X}_i)=0$ is going to cause problems unless you know how the space is generated.  Even taking limits can raise issues, with the Borel-Kolmogorov paradox illustrating what can happen if you take limits in different ways.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277388/pdf-of-sum-of-exponentials-conditioned-on-equality for an example

Thank you Henry for your comment. Yes, I am aware of that. The thing is i'm trying to remain agnostic about the structure of $\mathcal{X}i$. I am thinking about definiting it through conditional expectation: $K(x,A)=E[1{A}(Y)∣X=x], $ where $Y$ is the transformed point of $x$. I think this is going to keep me from the paradox. However, this expression alone does not reflect its random, uniform transformation nature. What do you think?

There are other problems. For example, how can you randomly pick a real number in $\mathbb{R}$ in a "uniformly random way"? Or, how can you randomly pick a positive integer in a 'uniformly random way"?

Thank you Michael. Yes thats also a concern. Thats why i said in the question if there's no good way i might just bound the space by large number M (thats actually what i did in the algorithm). I guess im more worried about the structure of the transition kernel itself at this point.
